# Display data from local json file on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am currently trying to display data from a local JSON file (universities.json) into a table on a webpage.  This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "universities.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched through so many questions on here and done countless google searches yet I cannot find out why this will not work.  This is just one iteration of the code;  I have tried various other ways too. I'm aware I don't have any code for a table included, but I have removed that until I can get the data pulling through in any format.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please include the sample data in `universities.json`? This will help us to replicate the issue

Comment: You can create a mock of the data and just call `myFunction`. This way you could know if the problem is with retrieving the json or with the function itself.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with that code, but I wouldn't be surprised if you found a big error message about reading files from the user's file system if you were to look at the Console in your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Another thing, when you debug this, check the network tab and see the response you get for the AJAX call

Answer (score 3):

Your browser security is not allowing you to make this request, and you are getting `CORS` error, in order to bypass this, you have two following options.

1.Alter your browser security settings.
For example, in Chrome, you can do this by navigating to Chrome installation folder and Run chrome with the following command, then try to test again in the browser

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

2.Run a Webserver locally and put all your file in the same path.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS error is due to browser security as Mahdi mentioned earlier.

If your HTML file is just opened from local drive in your browser (**client-side only**) and **not hosted on** a local nor remote **web server**, instead of using XMLHttpRequest(), you should try using FileReader() from pure JavaScript. Do something like this:

```js
  function fnUploadFile() {
    var objFileReader;
    var inputFile;
    var flLocalFile;

    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      // All the File APIs are supported.
    } else {
      alert('A required API is not supported on this browser. You need HTML5 browsers!');
      return; // abort execution
    }

    inputFile = document.getElementById('inLocallySelectedFile');

    if (!inputFile) {
      alert("File selector control not found!");
    } else if (!inputFile.files[0]) {
      alert("Have you selected a file yet? Select a file before clicking 'Process File'!");
    } else {
      // open and read file with JavaScript FileReader
      flLocalFile = inputFile.files[0];
      objFileReader = new FileReader();
      objFileReader.onload = function(event) {
        // event.target == FileReader
        var contents = event.target.result;
        fnConvertToJSON(contents);
      };
      objFileReader.readAsText(flLocalFile);
    }

    function fnConvertToJSON(results) {
      var JSONData = JSON.parse(results);
      var ctrlJSONDisplay = document.getElementById('JsonDataDisplay')
      ctrlJSONDisplay.innerHTML = "<strong><u>" + JSONData['name'] +
        "</u></strong> is <strong><u>" + JSONData['age'] +
        "</u></strong> years old and from the <strong><u>" +
        JSONData['country'] + "</u></strong>";
    }

  }
```

```html
    <form id="frmGetLocalFile" name="frmGetLocalFile" method="post">
      <h1>Select Your File</h1>
      <input type='file' accept="*" name='inLocallySelectedFile' id='inLocallySelectedFile'>
      <input type='button' id='btProcessFile' name="btProcessFile" value='Process File' onclick='fnUploadFile();'>
    </form>


    <div>
      <p>Assuming JSON File Content:</p>
      <pre>
{ 
   "name": "John", 
   "age" : 30, 
   "country" : "UK" 
}
</pre>
      <hr>
      <p>JSON Data read from local file:</p>
      <p id="JsonDataDisplay"></p>
    </div>
```

[See code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TechOnTheBeach/3gsa2y75/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/TechOnTheBeach/3gsa2y75/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't manage to serve files from within codesandbox.
However, following (serverside) codesample, does the trick:

```
const http = require("http");

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === "GET" && req.url == "/") {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
      });
      res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
            <div id="id01"></div>
          </body>
          <script>
            const getJson = () => {
              let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open('GET', '/getjson', true);
              xhr.onload = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                  json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  jsons = [];
                  Object.values(json).forEach((value,index) => {
                    jsons.push('<a href="'+value+'">"'+Object.keys(json)[index]+'"</a>');
                  });
                  jsons.forEach(item => document.querySelector('#id01').innerHTML += item+'<br>');

              };
              xhr.send();
            };
            getJson();
          </script>
        </html>`);
    }
    if (req.method === "GET" && req.url.match(/getjson/)) {
      let json = `{ "Univ1": "https://univ1.edu", "Univ2": "https://univ2.edu", "Univ3": "https://univ3.edu" }`;
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });
      res.end(json);
    }
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/j2yj6577q3