# Fetching json data locally on Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

It's simple I know but I've been pulling my hair all day to see why this conventional method of fetching json data isn't working at all???

A help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Sandbox over here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wood-0syn4

sortData.js

```
var myInit = {
 method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "default"
};

let myRequest = new Request("./dataset.json", myInit);

fetch(myRequest)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
    console.log(err);
  });
```

sample dataset.json

```
    {
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "gloss": {
    "title": "example glossary 2",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGMLZZZ",
          "SortAs": "SGMLZZ",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized  Language",
          "Acronym": "SGMAL",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markups"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Open your console.  And also look at the network response for that json request.  It's not json.  It's html

Comment: When ever you are having an issue with an ajax request you should always check the network console first.  Finding the request will #1 prove that it executed.  Then examining the response on the request will verify what you are getting back is what you expect.  These two steps should always be your first debugging steps.  This shouldn't take you "all day"

Comment: Side note: Your JSON contains two top-level objects separated by a comma. Did you mean to include them in an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display data from local json file on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611565/display-data-from-local-json-file-on-webpage)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tips @Taplar. Appreciate the response.

Comment: That's right, @AnisR. It was meant to be an array of objects so I sort of modified the json file and still screw it up lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path passed to your Request constructor needs to be relative to your index.html. Change it to "./src/dataset.json".

Comment: Oh wow, I never considered this at all. I got it! Thank you very much kind sir!